# x = disp(y) : "Too many output arguments"

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a completely general way to convert ***any*** value to a string in MATLAB.

Basically, I want to be able to write something like

```
x = disp(y);
```

The above fails with the error `Too many output arguments.`  (I was not able to find the source code for `disp`.)

Is there a single MATLAB function for converting ***any*** value into a string?

(Note that this function should behave like the identity when passed a string.)

Basically I'm looking for MATLAB's equivalent of Python's `str`.  I thought it might be `char`, but (for ***example***) `char(Inf)` fails to produce anything like the string `'Inf'`.  (Note: *that was just an example.  It does not begin to cover all the possibilities.*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[pm89's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16614908/1339280) has the right idea, but doesn't work because `evalc` requires a string as input. I suggest making your own function like so:

```
function str = anything2string(thing)

str = evalc('disp(thing)');
```

It works for anything that Matlab can display:

```
>> anything2string(3)
ans =
     3

>> anything2string(Inf)
ans =
   Inf

>> anything2string('hi')
ans =
hi

>> anything2string(1:4)
ans =
     1     2     3     4
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite the same as Python's `str`, but `num2str` works with `Inf` and handles strings as input.

```
num2str(Inf)
ans = Inf
num2str('some string')
ans = some string
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the exact same string as you see in your command window using evalc (evaluate and capture the result):

```
x = evalc('disp(y)'); % y could be anything displayable by Matlab!
```

Comment: I think you're on the right path, but this doesn't work because `evalc` requires a string as input.

Comment: @shoelzer: Oops! Yeah disp(y) should be string.
and x = evalc('disp(y)'); will work.
Thanks.

So refer to shoelzer's answer.